# Trouble with "variable lengths differ" error when comparing mixed models in R. Is there any way to compare two models when values are missing?

Tags: r, mixed-models

I am currently trying to compare different linear mixed models on R and encountered this error:

> Error in model.frame.default(data = datasum, drop.unused.levels = TRUE,  :
> variable lengths differ (found for 'Weather')

I know the error has occurred because "Weather" has less lines of data than every other variable and I could fix it by removing all other lines corresponding to Weathers missing values, but I would like to know if there is another way around this.

**For Example:**

```
m3a<-glmer(SumCount ~ Category + Kanuka_dens + PoplarWillow_dens + (1|Site)+(1|Survey), family=poisson, data=datasum
```

Does **not** get the error as all variables have 335 lines of data but...

```
m3b<-glmer(SumCount ~ Category + Kanuka_dens + PoplarWillow_dens + (1|Site)+(1|Weather), family=poisson, data=datasum
```

**Does ** get the error as "Weather" only has 330 lines compared to the 335 lines of every other variable.

I would like to compare the effectiveness of these two models against eachother without having to make the entire dataset smaller (as it would make all models less powerful), but am unsure if there's a way to do this?

**Note:** I have found the code "na.action=na.omit" but all attempts of inputing it into the model have still given me the same error.

Comment: If there are missing values for weather, then the model _only_ applies to the rows where there _is_ data for weather. Furthermore, if you try to pass in fewer entries for weather, then these will be out of alignment with your other variables. You don't _need_ to make the data frame smaller for all your analyses. Just have weather with NA values where there are missing measurements, and R will magically remove those rows from the analysis that includes them.

Comment: Just to clarify: does this mean if I change the blank portions of my raw data spreadsheet to "NA", R will read these values as not applicable and automatically account for them in my modelling?